# Allow using specific certificates only when connecting from specific hosts

Tags: openvpn, authentication, certificate

I set up my VPN users using certificates. The certificates are unique for every user, but they can be used on every PC.

Is there a way to restrict a certificate to a computer, e. g. based on its mac address or name?

Comment: Surely the certificates would be a pretty good identification of a computer since they're unique? If you have the problems of different hosts managing to obtain the private keys of other host's certificates then you may have other things to worry about.

Comment: torin, the certificate is bound to a user and not to a computer. the same certificate may be used on any computer. in my environment we have lots of users using several computers, at this time we simply copy their respective certificate files to each openvpn installation's config. the idea is that this is not longer possible.

Comment: Then realistically there's not much you can do, other than kostix's suggestion. However, you may want to consider how much you want to enforce such a policy since it may be more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly (how would you imagine this would be *checked and enforced* "automagically"? anyway) but you can do this with scripts—such as [`--client-connect`](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage). Such a script could inspect whatever it think is worth inspecting about the context of the client's connection and exit with a non-zero exit code if it thinks the client should be disconnected.